# Airflow adding a prefix to the base_url

Tags: flask, airflow, traefik

I'm running Airflow in a system with reverse-proxy (Traefik).
As the proxy is using a url prefix for routing, it would be great if Airflow could introduce a prefix to all routes. I saw the documentation about reverse proxys - but changing the **base_url** just redirects me back to the root (/). Therefore all requests of airflow can't be routed by the reverse proxy.

I need Airflow to listen on **example.com/airflow** insted of **example.com/**.
All request should include that prefix.
Is there a solution apart from introducing another proxy?

Thank you!

edit:

According to the [airflow docs](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration.html):

> Reverse Proxy
>
> Airflow can be set up behind a reverse proxy, with the ability to set its endpoint with great flexibility.
>
> For example, you can configure your reverse proxy to get:
>
> https://lab.mycompany.com/myorg/airflow/
>   To do so, you need to set the following setting in your airflow.cfg:
>
> **base_url** = http://my_host/myorg/airflow

By configuring the **base_url** to example.com/airflow, it is reachable by /airflow. But then it redirects based on the root again (/home, /login etc.). This does not work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this is an issue with Traefik.

The links are generated by your application, and are not modified in any way by Traefik. I would test without Traefik, and ensure that you are able to run your system at `/airflow` successfully, then re-introduce Traefik.

Comment: Yes that is correct.
Apache Airflow redirects wrong - that's the main issue.
But maybe there is also a workaround with Traefik (modifying the upstream e.g.).